# Issue while running ShinyDriver

Tags: r

I am facing few issues while running shinyDriver. below is the error. Can anyone help me please

```
app <- ShinyDriver$new(getwd())
Error in supervisor_start() : 
  processx supervisor was not ready after 5 seconds.
Type .Last.error.trace to see where the error occured
```

Comment: Error message is quite informative in this case: are you sure your working directory is actually the folder where your Shiny app is stored (either with a `ui.R` + `server.R` or `app.R`)? You can point the session to the right path with `ShinyDriver$new(path = "path/to/your_shiny_app`.

Comment: Yeah. It’s the right. It’s both ui.r and server.r

Comment: I mean the location is correct. Not sure why I get this error

Comment: You're right, with missing `app.R` it throws a different error message. Could you please provide the console output of `sessioninfo::session_info()`?

Comment: No actually with ui.R and server.R I was able to do it another system.